# Multiprocessing Pool non-blocking detection of finished tasks

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

Is there a way know that a process pool has finished running the tasks?

```
_process_pool = mp.Pool(processes=num_workers)
```

I am adding task onto the pool by batches:

```
for batch in gen_batches():
   _process_pool.map_async(fn, batch)
```

Is there a way to know when all tasks have been done? `callback` doesn't seem to work here. And I want to avoid to block the parent process by calling `_process_pool.join()`

Comment: pool is very limited compared to other multiprocessing methods.  I would check out "from multiprocess import Process, Pipe".  You can create workers (Process). when they are done they can pass a message to the main thread via Pipe.  If you go this route, make sure you read the thing about "daemon=True".  This will prevent orphaned children. https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues  and  https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.daemon

Comment: I can also use Value and Lock for it right ? Is there any drawback of using a global Value, and Lock instead of passing it on to processor-function ? 
It works correctly even with the global variables. Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Question**: Is there a way to know when all tasks have been done?

Append all `AsyncResult` from  `pool.map_async(...` to a `list`, for instance:

```
multiple_results = []
for batch in gen_batches():
   multiple_results.append( _process_pool.map_async(fn, batch) )


if all([ar.ready() for ar in multiple_results]):
    print('Pool done')
else:
    print('Pool any alive')
```

> **Python » 3.6.1 Documentation**: [multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult)

***Tested with Python:3.4.2***

Comment: Adding your previous note on the deleted answer would be good as well. That is ```map``` is blocking and ```map_async()``` is not! this was my culprit